# Send #hash from href to div in the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hash, href

I'm working on football website and i have an idea but i don't know if it possible.
I show all players of teams in a page and i wanna create a `<div>` that will show all statistics about a specific player clicking on the name.

If i click on the name i wanna show a `<div>` with information about that player in the same page (i will use z-index). This problem will be solved, but i wanna send id-player from href using hash to extract stats from db.

Clicking on `<a href="#201" class"xyz">player 201</a>` can `<div>` read **#201** and process it to search in the db?

(The idea is like infobox in Fantasy Premier League website. Someone know it??)

Thank you,
N

Comment: Please include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: You _wanna_ know about ajax, single page applications, and some more topics.

Answer (score 0):

You can include a div as

`<a href="#201" class"xyz">player 201</a>`

...

`<div id="201">Player1 details</div>`

But this work on same page. If you are going to use in different pages

`<a href="test.html#201" class"xyz">player 201</a>`

test.html
`<div id="201">Player1 details</div>`